# A smooth function which is nowhere real analytic, and preserves rationality of its argument

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

There are examples [$\!^{[1]}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#A_smooth_function_which_is_nowhere_real_analytic)[$\!^{[2]}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) of continuous infinitely differentiable ([class $C^\infty$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes)) functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ that are nowhere real analytic. I wonder if it is possible to construct such an example that preserves rationality of its argument, i.e. $f(x)\in\mathbb Q$ iff $x\in\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 1):

Values of Fabius function or it's first prime in dyadic rationals are rational,
[for example](http://www.neutreeko.net/mmm.htm#fabius).

Concernig non dyadic rational it seems to be an open question indeed.