# A smooth nowhere analytic function such that all derivatives are monotone

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples, analyticity, monotone-functions

Related questions that might provide some context: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/94634/19661) [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/620290/19661) [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1758891/19661) [(4)](https://mathoverflow.net/q/43462/9550)

---

Let's restrict our attention to real-valued functions on an open unit interval $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb R$.
There are examples [$\!^{[1]}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#A_smooth_function_which_is_nowhere_real_analytic)[$\!^{[2]}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) of [smooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes) (class $C^\infty$) functions that are nowhere [real-analytic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Definitions). Is there a smooth nowhere analytic function such that the function itself and its derivatives of any order are [monotone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function#Monotonicity_in_calculus_and_analysis)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is negative. All such functions are analytic. For totally monotone functions it was proved by [Bernstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions), and for the general case see [J. A. M. McHugh *"A proof of Bernstein's theorem on regularly monotonic functions"*](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-047-02/S0002-9939-1975-0354974-3/S0002-9939-1975-0354974-3.pdf).